# How to do unit tests for file reading functionality?

Tags: c#, file, unit-testing

So far I've been using the AAA method, which I would like to deploy into a set of 'mock-up' tests to test to see if a file exists, and if a file can be read etc..

The type of code I've been using is as followed:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Mul_TestValues0and0_EvaluatesTo0() {
    // Arrange
    var testArgument1 = 0;
    var testArgument2 = 0;
    var expectedResult = 0;

    // Act
    var actualResult = testedClass.Mul(testArgument1, testArgument2);

    //Assert
    var failMessage = String.Format(@"{0} * {1} evaluates to {2}, actual test result was {3}", testArgument1, testArgument2, expectedResult, actualResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult, failMessage);
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx

Comment: You could include files in your test project (set copy always ture) and use relative paths to the files in the test.

Comment: So you want to test system library, right? Shouldn't you test your code instead?

Comment: Yeah, I'm abit of a nooby with this stuff, I've basically got serialised data files in my program, which I need to run a set of tests on in a separate testing project to test to make sure the data is being read etc, can't really seem to find much useful information on the internet to help me achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a functional integration test, but not a unit test.

You should wrap the IO operations into a class with an interface which you can inject and mock in your SUT.

Then you can mock the result of a file read and test the rest of your business logic.

Does that make sense?

EDIT:
To give you a bit more context:

Unit testing literally means testing only one unit at a time. If you test a method which reads a file and does some serialization etc., then you are obviously testing a lot more than just one thing.

You are not only testing too much, but also duplicating a lot of testing effort, because you can assume that the system IO libraries have been already tested, so why would you want to repeat this effort? Abstract it into a thin wrapper class and focus your tests on your own domain logic.

Comment: Thanks, That's cleared it up better for me, I'll look into integration testing